# How not to duplicate code with typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm defining the following function:

```
const Text = ({
  align = 'left',
  children,
  className,
  color = 'middleGrey',
  size = 'big',
  light = false,
}: Props) => ()
```

And as I'm using typescript, I have defined the following interface:

```
interface Props {
  align: string
  children: ReactNode
  className: string
  color: string
  size?: string
  light: boolean
}
```

But this makes me write 2 times every property.

**Is there a better way to write this kind of code?**

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately not. Destructuring syntax does not support specifying type annotations. There is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) on this topic but it is open and not particularly active.